# OpenSWAN IPSec Connection to Cisco Meraki MX appliance

Tags: cisco, vpn, ipsec, linux

I have service I need to make VPN connections to.

I have this working perfectly fine in windows, setup was quick, easy and straightforward.

I am now trying to achieve the same connection in Linux using OpenSWAN but my connection is failing with:

```
117 "MyConnection" #115: STATE_QUICK_I1: initiate
010 "MyConnection" #115: STATE_QUICK_I1: retransmission; will wait 20s for response
010 "MyConnection" #115: STATE_QUICK_I1: retransmission; will wait 40s for response
031 "MyConnection" #115: max number of retransmissions (2) reached STATE_QUICK_I1.  No 
  acceptable response to our first Quick Mode message: perhaps peer likes no proposal
000 "MyConnection" #115: starting keying attempt 2 of an unlimited number, but releasing 
  whack
```

I'm not exactly sure what this means, though have Googled a lot though I'm guessing I have some configuration parameters wrong.

In windows I have the following configuration defined (everything else is default)

Username and password

L2TP/IPSec selected

PSK defined in advanced options of the L2TP/IPSec connection

Require Encryption turned on

Unencrypted password (PAP) checked

And it all just works - unfortunately I'm not sure how to translate these settings fully to relevant ipsec.conf parameters.

The VPN I'm connecting to is a Cisco meraki MX appliance if that helps...

I guess if anyone has a sample config for an openSWAN connection to Cisco meraki MX appliance that would be a helpful starting point, but more specifically if someone can translate the windows VPN settings to ipsec.conf options that would be the most useful thing

Comment: It is very likely you have a misconfiguration in OpenSWAN, especially as this works from Windows. I would suggest you tripple check the configuration and also increase the logging as the logs you have provided don't provide much info to the problem. The line `No acceptable response to our first Quick Mode message: perhaps peer likes no proposal` suggests that perhaps you need to configured aggressive mode, or perhaps you haven't configured the correct transforms. Please check your configuration and provide more detailed logging output.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing with Meraki VPN. Meraki said to follow the following guide to make it work. I haven't had any luck yet, but still trying. I am thinking of returning the equipment if I can't connect using Linux. Appreciate any input from anyone who had successfully connected VPN from Ubuntu to Meraki. [https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/L2TP/IPsec_VPN_client_setup#OpenSwan](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/L2TP/IPsec_VPN_client_setup#OpenSwan)

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/815499/318507) quoted below and [the blog post mentioned in it](http://blog.z-proj.com/enabling-l2tp-over-ipsec-on-ubuntu-16-04/) to get a connection working to Meraki from Ubuntu 16.04.

A PPA exists for network-manager-l2tp:

You can use

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install network-manager-l2tp
```

To install the network manager l2tp that supports L2TP for Ubuntu 16.04

Walkthrough for building from source: http://blog.z-proj.com/enabling-l2tp-over-ipsec-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: Unfortunately, host configurations are explicitly off-topic here.